# How can I install the util linux version of the column command in 18.04?

Tags: command-line, software-installation

The version of the column command available via [Util Linux](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/column.1.html) is far more comprehensive than the one included in [bsdmainutils](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/column.1.html). It includes extensive options for output formatting. I would really like to use the util linux version on 18.04 but I can't work out how to install it.

The current command is installed by `bsdmainutils`:

```
$ dpkg -S "$( which column )"
bsdmainutils: /usr/bin/column
```

The `util-linux` package does not seem to include the command:

```
$ dpkg -L util-linux | grep column | wc -l
0
```

My question is how can I install the comprehensive version of this command? Is there a snap somewhere or do I need to build it from source?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am on Ubuntu 18.04 and using the new version of column.
My exact steps were:

1. Download [version 2.35 tar.gz (~10MB)](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/v2.35/)
2. Extract the compressed contents (right click, extract)
3. Inside the new folder, `./configure`, then `make`.
4. Moved the newly created column binary into my path as column2 just in case something was relying on the BSD version.
5. Profit.

New column is amazing, just for the record.

Answer (score 9):

There is a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/util-linux/+bug/1705437) on this problem you can subscribe to. The more people that subscribe the greater chances it will be fixed:

> The 'column' program included in upstream util-linux
>   (https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git/tree/text-utils/column.c)
>   is newer than the included in the bsdmainutil package
>   (https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/bsdmainutils/bsdmainutils.git/tree/usr.bin/column/column.c).
>   However, debian/rules from util-linux package states the opposite, and
>   therefore Ubuntu now is using 'column' from bsdmainutils instead of
>   the util-linux one.

Comment: Nice finding! Any workaround until it’s fixed? Is it possible to install only this one tool from https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux?

Comment: @dessert Thanks. My instinct would be to download the `column` command source code and recompile it anytime `bsdmainutils` updates it.

Comment: Thanks, I found the bug report and the source code after asking the question yesterday. I had a go at trying to compile just column. The file `Documentation/howto-build-sys.txt` suggests something like `./configure --disable-all-programs --enable-column`. I gave up after autotools was complaining about not finding `/usr/share/aclocal/pkg.m4` despite it existing. It would be good if someone with more autotools foo could add an answer on how to compile util-linux `column` from source.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix good suggestion re subscribing to the bug report, I'll find my launchpad login and subscribe.

Comment: I note that a Ubuntu developer has marked the bug won't fix on 2019-01-06. The rationale is that it should get fixed in Debian and then will be automatically available in Ubuntu.

Comment: Just ran into this issue, did anyone ever find a workaround?

Comment: Debian bug: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=908975

Answer (score 4):

Based on the answer from @ColonelBuendia this worked for me on `20.04`:

```
$ cd ~/Downloads/
$ wget https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/v2.35/util-linux-2.35-rc1.tar.gz
$ aunpack util-linux-2.35-rc1.tar.gz
$ cd util-linux-2.35-rc1/
$ ./configure
$ make column
$ cp .libs/column ~/bin/
$ cd ..
$ rm -rf util-linux-2.35-rc1*
$ column --version
column from util-linux 2.35-rc1
```

Comment: think it's better fetching the source package with apt-get source util-linux, it will ensure compatibility with the dependent libs, as long as you keep the source up-to-date.

Comment: @bac0n good suggestion, I'll give that a try and write it up when i have some time :)

Answer (score 1):

For Jammy (Ubuntu 22.04), I tried following the answer from htaccess, but newer versions of `column` (2.39.2 is what I'm trying to install) require an update to `libsmartcols`. I tried grabbing the latest package from the latest Ubuntu distro here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/amd64/util-linux/download, but that has some libc dependencies that aren't included in 22.04.

Instead, just reading the install docs for `util-linux` (`cat ./Documentation/howto-compilation.txt`), I was able to install the whole package:

```sh
# Install autogen dependencies
$ sudo apt-get install gettext bison autopoint -y 

# Grab and untar package
$ cd ~/Downloads
$ wget https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/v2.39/util-linux-2.39.2.tar.gz
$ tar -xf util-linux-2.39.2.tar.gz && cd util-linux-2.39.2

# Build with autogen
$ ./autogen.sh && ./configure && make column

# Backup original
$ sudo mv /bin/column /bin/column_2_37 # or whatever version original is
$ sudo mv /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmartcols.so.1 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmartcols.so.1_2_37

# Copy new version
$ sudo cp .libs/column /bin/ && sudo cp .libs/libsmartcols.so.1 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

# Check version
$ column -V
» column from util-linux 2.39.2

# Clean up
$ cd .. && rm -rf util-linux-2.39.2
```

Comment: Nice, although I wish someone would just write a nice replacement in rust or zig so we didn't have to go to such trouble!

Comment: Seriously @htaccess

Answer (score 0):

For ubuntu 18.04

1. dpkg -l | grep -i util-linux //find a nearest version
2. get https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/v2.31/util-linux-2.31.tar.gz
3. cd util-linux-2.31
4. ./configure
5. make column
6. sudo cp .libs/column /usr/bin/column
7. column -V

works.

Comment: It's unnecessarily complicated. Why not use `sudo apt install util-linux`?